# Issue with using HTML for Floating button in react and not material UI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, floating-action-button

Working on a requirement that needs the usage of floating button to hide and show a menu, implementing this using material UI functions as needed, but if i change this to a button with icon using normal html and css doesn't work as required.
Expected behavior - on click of hide button present on the menu the menu section is hidden when a floating button is shown up, this button is used to flow around the screen on click and mouse drag and can be released freely and when clicked again the menu is again shown,
Where as if i change this to a normal html and css button the behavior is a bubble that appears with drag of the button and also the until i click back i wont be able to release the arrow from the button until clicked.

```
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 75, y: 75 });

    //Ref are needed instead of states so they can be used in handle move
    const vector = useRef({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    const clicked = useRef(false);
    const oldPosition = useRef(position);

    useEffect(() => {
        const cachedPos = localStorage.getItem('OpenMenuIconPosition');
        if (cachedPos) {
            const newPos = JSON.parse(cachedPos);
            const clampNewPos = {
                x: clamp(newPos.x, 0, window.innerWidth - 60),
                y: clamp(newPos.y, 0, window.innerHeight - 60)
            };
            setPosition(clampNewPos);
            oldPosition.current = clampNewPos;
        }
    }, []);

    const handleMouseDown = e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        clicked.current = true;
        vector.current = {
            x: e.clientX - position.x,
            y: e.clientY - position.y
        };
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
    };

    const handleMove = e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (clicked.current === true) {
            setPosition({
                x: clamp(e.clientX - vector.current.x, 0, window.innerWidth - 60),
                y: clamp(e.clientY - vector.current.y, 0, window.innerHeight - 60)
            });
        }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        clicked.current = false;
        if (Math.abs(oldPosition.current.x - position.x) < 5 && Math.abs(oldPosition.current.y - position.y) < 5) showMenu();
        oldPosition.current = position;
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
        localStorage.setItem('OpenMenuIconPosition', JSON.stringify(position));
    };

    const handleTouchDown = e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        clicked.current = false;
        vector.current = {
            x: e.changedTouches[0].clientX - position.x,
            y: e.changedTouches[0].clientY - position.y
        };
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
    };

    const handleTouchMove = e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (clicked.current === true) {
            setPosition({
                x: clamp(e.changedTouches[0].clientX - vector.current.x, 0, window.innerWidth - 60),
                y: clamp(e.changedTouches[0].clientY - vector.current.y, 0, window.innerHeight - 60)
            });
        }
    };

    const handleTouchUp = e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        clicked.current = false;
        if (Math.abs(oldPosition.current.x - position.x) < 5 && Math.abs(oldPosition.current.y - position.y) < 5) showMenu();
        oldPosition.current = position;
        window.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
        localStorage.setItem('OpenMenuIconPosition', JSON.stringify(position));
    };
    const [overButton, setOverButton] = useState(false);

    const mouseMoveListener = e => {
        if (e.clientX < 200 && e.clientY < 200) {
            setOverButton(true);
        } else {
            setOverButton(false);
        }
    };
    const limitedListener = useRef(throttle(mouseMoveListener, 1000));

    const { updateState } = useContext(AppContext);
    const showMenu = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', limitedListener.current);
        setOverButton(false);

        updateState('isMenuHidden', false);
    }

    return (
        <div overButton className="floating-wrapper"><a className="floating-btn"
            onMouseUp={e => handleMouseUp(e)}
            onMouseDown={e => handleMouseDown(e)}
            onTouchStart={e => handleTouchDown(e)}
            onTouchEnd={e => handleTouchUp(e)}
            style={{ top: position.y, left: position.x }}>
            <img src="/imgs/action_add.svg" alt="Menu" className="menu-icon" /></a></div>

    );
}
```